# Rewrite_rule to protect files in directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

How do I add some conditions to my `htaccess` so that if I enter :

`http://example.com/protectedpage.php`

It redirect to:

`http://example.com/no_access.php`

Here is a list of files that I would like to protect from users:

**protectedpage1**, **protectedpage2**, **protectedpage3**,...

How do I achive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your Root/.htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteBase / 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/protectedpage1\.php [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/protectedpage2\.php [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/protectedpage3\.php
 RewriteRule .* /no_access.php [L,R]
```

RewriteConditions check if the Requested URI string contains any of the spacified files then Server will redirect them to the no_access.php page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex alternation and have a simple `RedirectMatch` rule like this:

```
RedirectMatch ^/(protectedpage1|protectedpage2|protectedpage3)\.php$ /no_access.php
```